# Fitting sinusoid to noisy data

Tags: fitting, envelope

I have a set of data:

```
data1={0.438947, 0.421796, 0.257979, -0.0113562, -0.304228, -0.434637, -0.244146, 0.103227, 0.476592, 0.688494, 0.544246, 0.148493, 0.172431, 0.0354982, -0.331193, -0.344282, -0.00962893, 0.373348, 0.679059, 0.58302, 0.184679, -0.236453, 0.166275, 0.175942, 0.0251669, 0.100451, 0.511637, 0.637384, 0.430186, -0.0118105, -0.292176, -0.184197, 0.199443, 0.150381, 0.16512, 0.001854, -0.260791, 0.0622488, 0.425933, 0.599488, 0.47702, 0.0970701, -0.209052, -0.220244, 0.173392, 0.134602, 0.240986, 0.338698, 0.0220978, -0.224613, -0.109723, 0.176388, 0.454605, 0.557959, 0.302164, 0.17482, 0.19531, 0.40853, 0.214071, 0.00811249, -0.0842581, -0.00985491, 0.200964, 0.430605, 0.440398, 0.243201, 0.167068, 0.148824, 0.160405, 0.290912, 0.350251, 0.278384, 0.116044, 0.0321556, 0.0705789, 0.174297, 0.28836, 0.194055, 0.162784, 0.199375, 0.202781, 0.13725, 0.142673, 0.14058, 0.174253, 0.193957, 0.20005, 0.151823, 0.159523, 0.171071, 0.129125, 0.128131, 0.153288, 0.17511, 0.231478, 0.228416, 0.203896, 0.169086, 0.0966604, 0.158022}
```

which has decaying sinusoidal oscillations within an envelope. If I try to fit this using the `NonLinearModelFit` command:

```
l = Table[l, {l, 0, 99}];
Data1 = MapThread[List, {l, data1}];

model=NonlinearModelFit[Data1, s Exp[-a t] (Sin[b t + c]) + d, {{s, 0.4}, {a, 0}, {b, 0.7}, {c, 2}, {d, 0.15}}, t] 
Show[ListLinePlot[Data1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calisto MT", 20, Bold}], Plot[model[t], {t, 0, 99}, PlotLabel -> Framed[model[t]], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black, Dashed}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calisto MT", 20, Bold}]]
```

I get the graph in the Figure below. [image]

where the purple line is the data and the black dashed line is the fit. This is clearly not a very good fit to the data. Is there a more accurate way of fitting data like this?

Comment: `NonLinearModelFit` is a fine tool, but you won't get a good fit unless your function can be made to match the data. I don't see an exponentially decaying sinusoid here, and neither does `NonLinearModelFit`. Perhaps a more realistic physical model is in order.

Comment: To echo @JohnDoty 's comment:  Do you need just to "describe" the data or approximate the process that generates the data?  If the former, then you'll likely need some nonparametric regression technique (kernel regression, gams, loess, etc.).  If the latter, then you'll need to describe the process that generates the data which would account for the varying amplitudes and frequencies.  The point is that it takes more than just having data.

Comment: @AntonAntonov.  I think I fixed the code by adding in `model = NonlinearModelFit....`

Comment: @JimB, yes, I figured `model` is missing. I sort of wanted JJH to fix it...

Comment: @JimB, the latter is what I'm hoping to model. I'm currently trying a model where I split the data into small sections and fit then individually.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you know about the process that generates the data if you're going to split the data into small sections and fit individually.  With a "good looking" fit you'll get a description of the data but no better understanding of the data generation process.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there may be a problem with your sampling frequency.  For example, consider this sampling of a sinusoid, producing the data in purple.

If you can increase your sampling frequency your data might be better to fit.

```
tab = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 22 Pi, 0.01}];

Show[lp = ListLinePlot[First /@ Partition[tab, 306],
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Purple}],
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 22 Pi}]]
```

[image]

Nevertheless, poor sampling does not stop `NonlinearModelFit`.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[tab, {a Exp[-b t] Cos[c t + d]}, {a, b, c, d}, t];

Show[lp, Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 22 Pi}]]
```

[image]